# ILoggerFactory does not contain a definition for addconsole

Tags: asp.net-core-2.1, .net-7.0, iloggerfactory

I have upgrade a project from .NET Core 2.1 to .NET 7.

The original project had the following segment in `startup.cs`:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
        loggerFactory.AddConsole(LogLevel.Debug);
        loggerFactory.AddConsole(LogLevel.Information);
        loggerFactory.AddConsole(LogLevel.Warning);
        loggerFactory.AddConsole(LogLevel.Error);
}
```

In the upgraded project I get an error:

> Iloggerfactory does not contain a definition for AddConsole.

Wonder what the equivalent would be in .NET 7 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at some documentation, I found the following help to fix it:

```
        services.AddLogging(loggingBuilder =>
        {
            loggingBuilder.AddDebug();
            loggingBuilder.AddConsole();
        });
```

in ConfigureServices

Answer (score 0):

Make sure this package is installed in your project `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console`.

I would have the `Configure` in  `Startup.cs` like this:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    LoggerFactory.Create(builder =>
    {
        builder.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Debug);
        builder.AddFilter("Microsoft", LogLevel.Information);
        builder.AddFilter("System", LogLevel.Warning);

        builder.AddConsole();
    });
}
```

You can find more here [Logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/logging?tabs=command-line).

Another Option is to do this in your `Program.cs`

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).ConfigureLogging((logging) =>
    {
        logging.ClearProviders(); //Optional: Remove other logging providers if needed.

        logging.AddConsole(options =>
        {
            // Set the minimum log level for the console
            options.LogToStandardErrorThreshold = LogLevel.Debug;
        });
    })
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
        });
```

Comment: in this option: 

    LoggerFactory.Create(builder =>
    {
        builder.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Debug);
        builder.AddFilter("Microsoft", LogLevel.Information);
        builder.AddFilter("System", LogLevel.Warning);

        builder.AddConsole();
    });




do I not have to add the above created object to something?

Comment: The `LoggerFactory.Create` method will return an instance of `ILoggerFactory`. Which you can use to create your `ILogger` instances for logging within your app. [Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Fkdjzu)

Answer (score 0):

In the .net 7, the console log is installed by default by the logging extension.

You could use below codes inside the program.cs

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Logging.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Debug);
builder.Logging.AddConsole();
```

The SetMinimumLevel is used for set the log level for the LogDebug,LogInformation,LogWarning,LogError,Critical.

You could also set it by using the appsettings.json, like below

```
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  }
```

More details about how to use it inside the .net 7, I suggest you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-7.0).